# Saving many files to AWS S3 bucket in parallel is much slower than chunking and saving

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that reads a JSON file from S3, which contains around 500 objects.

As part of this lambda job, it takes those 500 objects and saves them separately. Each object is tiny, just around 500 bytes.

My code is currently handling it by saving all files in parallel and letting S3 handle the load. S3 docs suggest that it supports **at least** 3,500 PUT requests for a second.

```js
// saveFile calls S3 under the hood (S3.upload)
await Promise.all(
  transactions.map((transaction) => saveFile(transaction))
);
```

I enabled logging for the AWS object (`aws-sdk`) and wanted to see what the timing looks like. I was surprised to see that the time for each upload is increasing, not in correlation to the file size (which is small) but in correlation to the number of objects I'm trying to upload. It got to as high as 8 seconds for an upload operation to complete.

I tried doing the same thing but now I was handling the chunking:

```js
for (const chunk of chunk(transactions, 50)) {
  await Promise.all(
    chunk.map((transaction) => saveFile(transaction))
  );
}
```

Running the new code results in a **significantly** faster execution time. The upload time was around 400ms this time.

This weird result got me thinking that maybe something is throttled/queued on my code side. Then, I suddenly remembered that AWS limits the sockets for the underlying https agent to 50 by default. So now [following their docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/node-configuring-maxsockets.html), I tried changing it to a high number, thinking that what's happening is that since I'm issuing 500 requests in parallel, they are all just stuck in the queue and affect each other, somehow.

```js
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const https = require('https');
const agent = new https.Agent({ maxSockets: 100000, keepAlive: true });
aws.config.update({
  httpOptions: { agent },
});

// ...

await Promise.all(
  transactions.map((transaction) => saveFile(transaction))
);
```

Unfortunately, it did not work. The high requests time is still there. I've tried many values for the `maxSockets` attribute, even trying plugging an http client instead of an https client, but of course, I got an error that I try to access an https resource, and it failed.

Any idea what could be the issue and how can I solve it?

Comment: There are multiple factors not visible affecting the performance. Size of the lambda runtime affecting memory and network, we don't see how the `saveFile` is defined and as far I recall the `map` fn is not parallel

Comment: Hey @gusto2, The map function is not parallel, however, it yields promises. The promise isn't sync, but async, hence I can easily convert all of my existing transactions into promises and await them. As for the `saveFile` function, it just was an easy way to obscure `aws` v2 hideous API implementation. It just calls the `upload` function on the SDK. The lambda size doesn't really matter here (tried with various sizes), it seems more like networking/queueing issue rather than CPU/memory one

Comment: Yes, you have promises, but these are processed one by one in an event loop, not really in parallel as assumed from the question (as far I know how NodeJS works). Even parallel processing when done properly has some limits (thread pool,, ..).  And then I'd advice to check if the connection pool is reused (the most expensive op may be establishing SSL)

Comment: @gusto2 Since the promises internal is HTTP communication it is non-blocking and being executed on another queue. When we use `map` to create the promises we aren't waiting for each one of them to execute. They are executing in parallel. I'm not sure what's causing the slowdown. The connections are being used and not re-established. The limit is the `maxSockets` which I tried to raise but does not seem like it works

Comment: Probably a silly question but wanted to get the obvious out of the way: have you made sure your `maxSockets` setting actually took effect?

Comment: @jingx yes I did

Comment: I think it's because you are denial of service attacking yourself. Sounds odd to say it, but basically that 8 seconds is probably a queued upload, if you increase the load but decrease the file count in the same ratio does the problem stay the same... Maybe bigger files but less of them something comparable to test?

Comment: @XylozQuin I've conducted many tests with many different lambda memory sizes and also reached out to AWS support about it. My findings are relatively the same as theirs - there is some limitation about the actual `maxSockets` you can have and it increases with the memory allocated to the lambda, just like with CPU.  I'm still talking with them trying to confirm this theory and maybe even get a list indicating what the `maxSockets` are for each memory size

Comment: So yes then, xD 

You maxed out your available resources and prevented (Denied) further access to processing services. 

Even if you could Unthrottle your Sockets you can't physically write more than the CPU threshold, if it is one file at a time writes, then all the sockets you like... bottle necked to one file at time.


This is why saving files is generally not preffered over saving references to a file store.

Instead of writing the whole file, you just write the address.